# Linux : dirty page writeback and concurrent write

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel, memory-mapped-files, page-caching

Background : in Java I'm memory mapping a file (shared).

I'm writing some value at the address 0 of that file. I understand the corresponding PAGE in the PAGE CACHE is flagged as DIRTY and will be written later depending on the dirty_ratio and the like settings.

So far so good.

But I'm wondering what is happening when writing once more at the address 0 while the kernel is writing back the dirty page to the file. Is my process blocked somehow waiting for the writeback to be completed?

Comment: With what permissions are you memory mapping the file? A snippet of code would be very helpful.

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- : as for the code : once I got the memory mapped file buffer I'm simply buffer.putInt( addr, value ) quite randomly possibly writing several times different values at the same addresse in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It may be.  It is only necessary when the device-level I/O requests include a checksum alongside the written data.  Otherwise, the first write may be torn, but it can then be corrected by the second write.

As always, carefully consider your safety against power-failure, kernel crashes etc.

The waiting is allegedly avoided in btrfs.  (Also, by happenstance, in the legacy ext3 filesystem.  But not ext4 or ext2).

This looks like it is a bit of a moving target.  The above (as far as I could tell) describes the first optimization of this "stable page write" code, following the complaints when it was first introduced.  The commit description mentions several possibilities for future changes.

1. [bdi: allow block devices to say that they require stable page writes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/7d311cdab663)
2. [mm: only enforce stable page writes if the backing device requires it](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1d1d1a767206)

### Does my device currently use "stable page writes"?

There is a sysfs attribute you can look at, called [`stable_pages_required`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7d311cdab663f/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-bdi#L52)